# How can I add an empty element to a tree of elements styled with flex without changing the design?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to add an empty element say a div or span below css.searchBarDiv closing below the css.searchBarButton without changing the look. Currently, if I do that it moves the search button to the next line and hides the css.searchBarInput div.

Here's the code for reference:

```
<div className={css.searchBarBorder}>
          <div className={css.searchBarBase}>

            <div className={css.searchBarFirstDiv}>
              <label className={css.searchBarLabel} htmlFor="location-search-input">
                <div className={css.searchBarFirstDivContent}>
                  <div className={css.searchBarHeadingFont}>Location</div>
                  <input
                    id="location-search-input"
                    className={css.searchBarInput}
                  />
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div className={css.seperator} />

            <div className={css.searchBarDiv}>             {/*Enter an empty element below this*/}
              <div className={css.datePartStyling}>
                <div className={css.searchBarDivContent}>
                  <div className={css.searchBarHeadingFont}>Date</div>
                  <div className={css.searchBarInput}>Add when you want to go</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={css.searchBarButton}>
                <a className={css.button}>Search</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.searchBarBorder {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.searchBarBase {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 0px;
}
.searchBarFirstDiv {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  min-width: 0px;
}
.seperator {
  align-self: center;
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  height: 32px;
}
.searchBarDiv {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0px;
  flex: 0.95 0 auto;
}
.datePartStyling {
  flex: 1 0 0% !important;
  width: 0px !important;
}
.searchBarButton {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-self: center;
}
```

Kindly guide me on how can this be done. All answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give the width on the parent 100%. For children whose 3 you have to give 33% width each, and in the child who has to have a disappearing element, add an additional div inside which is to disappear. If it disappears, it won't break anything.
100% main box
33% div
33% div
33% of the div where you want something to disappear
element that disappears
.
Or just add parent for disappear element

Comment: its not moving the button back in line